# Trim the left and right of an array

Tags: javascript, lodash

How do you trim contiguous falsey members from only the left and right of an array?

I would like to write a method that does something like this

```
getLookupKey('prefix', 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', 'suffix');
// => 'prefix.prefix.middle.suffix.suffix'

getLookupKey(null, 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', null);
// => 'prefix.middle.suffix'

getLookupKey('name');
// => 'name'

getLookupKey();
// => ''

getLookupKey('prefix', null, 'suffix');
// => throws error
```

Where `getLookupKey` takes a variable number of arguments and produces a lookup key.

I would like this method to ignore nulls on the left and right of the array but throw if there are any nulls in the middle.

Here are some behavior rules:

- Array members that evaluate to false starting from the beginning of the array until a member evaluates to true should be removed.
- Array members that evaluate to false started from the end of the array until a member evaluates to true should be removed.
- Members that evaluate to false that are between members that evaluate to true should cause the method to throw an error.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this was downvoted. The question is unasked, unique and has utility, and my answer is useful as far as I can tell... Is there something I missed?

Comment: Maybe your answer had to be included to your question, to show your effort.

Comment: I don't understand why. It's a solution, not an attempt to get to a solution. If it's an answer, shouldn't it go in the answer section?

Comment: What defines `middle`, must there be a minimum of 2/3 arguments (or a minimum of 5) `"prefix", "middle"` or `"prefix", "middle", "suffix"` and 4 arguments `"prefix", "middle", "middle", "suffix"` and then 5 arguments or more `"prefix", "prefix", "middle", "suffix", "suffix"`, the first 2 are always counted as `"prefix"` and the last 2 are always counted as `"suffix"`. You question is not very clear wrt how it is supposed to work. And when you say `null`, do you mean that or you mean that the argument evaluates `false`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It's pretty clear that the question is talking about array members that evaluate to false since the question says "contiguous falsey members". I think the definition of 'middle' is pretty clear but I will edit the question to make both of these points more clear.

Comment: @Xotic750, Is it not clear from "How do you trim contiguous falsey members from only the left and right of an array"? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question, here's my take on the solution. I used `dropWhile` and `dropRightWhile` to do most of the heavy lifting.

`dropWhile` will drop all values that are false from the left until it finds a true value. `dropRightWhile` will drop all values that are false from the right until it finds a true value. The `any` method is used to test if any false values exist within members.

The `isFalse` method is just a method to check for falsey values. It's just a `js` trick to convert any value to a boolean value.

```js
function log(value) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(value, null, 2) + "\n"
}

function getLookupKey() {
    var keyParts = trimArrayFalsey(_.toArray(arguments));
    if (_.any(keyParts, isFalse)) {
        throw new Error('Center null');
    }
    return keyParts.join('.');
}

function trimArrayFalsey(arr) {
    return _.chain(arr)
            .dropWhile(isFalse)
            .dropRightWhile(isFalse)
            .value();
}
        
function isFalse(value) {
    return !!!value;
}

log(getLookupKey('prefix', 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', 'suffix'));
// => 'prefix.prefix.middle.suffix.suffix'

log(getLookupKey(null, 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', null));
// => 'prefix.middle.suffix'

log(getLookupKey('name'));
// => 'name'

log(getLookupKey());
// => ''

log(getLookupKey('prefix', null, 'suffix'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.5.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: @Xotic750 I can't remember where I read it, but there's some obscure case where `!value` doesn't work and `!!!value` will make sure it works, but I don't remember where I read this. Regardless, it definitely would be best to use `!value`.. It was one of those obscure-browser specific bugs..

Comment: I was not aware of `dropWhile`, etc. That's an interesting take on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not using any libraries, just pure Javascript, so has more lines of code than the sugared syntax of a library. Should have better performance than using multiple loops as it is just a single loop, will be more noticeable with a larger number of arguments.

Works by looking at each end of the array-like `arguments` object, marking the `start` and `end` positions where elements do not evaluate to `false`. Once marked further elements are concatenated to the `result` string. If we have content then we concatenate the `start` and `end` element (if they exist) to give the full content, finally `return`ing the `result`.

```js
function getLookupKey() {
    var length = arguments.length,
        result = '',
        index,
        start,
        end,
        stop,
        value;

    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
        if (arguments[index]) {
            start = index;
            break;
        }
    }

    for (index = length; index > start; index -= 1) {
        if (arguments[index]) {
            end = index;
            break;
        }
    }

    stop = end - 1;
    for (index = start + 1; index < end; index += 1) {
        value = arguments[index];
        if (!value) {
            throw new SyntaxError('middle evaluates false');
        }
        
        result += value;
        if (index !== stop) {
            result += '.';
        }
    }

    if (typeof start === 'number') {
        if (result) {
            result = '.' + result;
        }

        result = arguments[start] + result;
    }

    if (typeof end === 'number') {
        result += '.' + arguments[end];
    }

    return result;
}

function log(str) {
    document.getElementById('out').textContent += str + '\n';
}

var tests = [
    [
        [null, 'middle'], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'middle', null, null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, 'middle', null, null, null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        ['prefix1', 'prefix2', 'middle', 'suffix1', 'suffix2'], 'prefix1.prefix2.middle.suffix1.suffix2'
    ],
    [
        [null, 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', null], 'prefix.middle.suffix'
    ],
    [
        ['name'], 'name'
    ],
    [
        [null], ''
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, null], ''
    ],
    [
        ['a', null, null, null], 'a'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'b'], 'b'
    ],
    [
        [], ''
    ],
    [
        ['prefix', null, 'suffix'], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, null, 'a', 'b', 'c', null, null], 'a.b.c'
    ],
    [
        ['a', null, 'b'], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle', null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, 'middle2', 'middle3', null], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', 'middle2', 'middle3', null, 'middle4', 'middle5', null], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, null, null, null, 'middle2', null], Error
    ]
];

function test(fn) {
    var length = tests.length,
        index,
        expected,
        args,
        actual;

    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
        args = tests[index][0];
        expected = tests[index][1];
        if (typeof expected === 'string') {
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }
          
            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else if (expected === Error) {
            expected = 'middle evaluates false';
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }
          
            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else {
            log('Test ' + index + ': coder error');
        }
    }
}

test(getLookupKey);
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Simple but less efficient than the above, in ES5

```js
function getLookupKey() {
    var arr = Array.prototype.reduce.call(arguments, function (acc, arg) {
        if (arg || acc.length) {
            acc.push(arg);
        }
        
        return acc;
    }, []).reduceRight(function (acc, arg) {
        if (arg || acc.length) {
            acc.unshift(arg);
        }
        
        return acc;
    }, []);
    
    if (!arr.every(Boolean)) {
        throw new SyntaxError('middle evaluates false');
    }
    
    return arr.join('.');
}

function log(str) {
    document.getElementById('out').textContent += str + '\n';
}

var tests = [
    [
        [null, 'middle'], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'middle', null, null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, 'middle', null, null, null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        ['prefix1', 'prefix2', 'middle', 'suffix1', 'suffix2'], 'prefix1.prefix2.middle.suffix1.suffix2'
    ],
    [
        [null, 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', null], 'prefix.middle.suffix'
    ],
    [
        ['name'], 'name'
    ],
    [
        [null], ''
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, null], ''
    ],
    [
        ['a', null, null, null], 'a'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'b'], 'b'
    ],
    [
        [], ''
    ],
    [
        ['prefix', null, 'suffix'], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, null, 'a', 'b', 'c', null, null], 'a.b.c'
    ],
    [
        ['a', null, 'b'], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle', null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, 'middle2', 'middle3', null], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', 'middle2', 'middle3', null, 'middle4', 'middle5', null], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, null, null, null, 'middle2', null], Error
    ]
];

function test(fn) {
    var length = tests.length,
        index,
        expected,
        args,
        actual;

    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
        args = tests[index][0];
        expected = tests[index][1];
        if (typeof expected === 'string') {
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }
          
            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else if (expected === Error) {
            expected = 'middle evaluates false';
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }
          
            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else {
            log('Test ' + index + ': coder error');
        }
    }
}

test(getLookupKey);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es5-shim/4.1.7/es5-shim.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Simple but less efficient again, in ES6

```js
function fVal(test, alt) {
    return test !== -1 ? test : alt;
}

function getLookupKey() {
    var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        length = arr.length,
        begin = fVal(arr.findIndex(Boolean), length),
        end = length - fVal(arr.slice().reverse().findIndex(Boolean), 0);

    arr = arr.slice(begin, end);
    if (!arr.every(Boolean)) {
        throw new SyntaxError('middle evaluates false');
    }

    return arr.join('.');
}

function log(str) {
    document.getElementById('out').textContent += str + '\n';
}

var tests = [
    [
        [null, 'middle'], 'middle'],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'middle', null, null], 'middle'],
    [
        [null, null, 'middle', null, null, null], 'middle'],
    [
        ['prefix1', 'prefix2', 'middle', 'suffix1', 'suffix2'], 'prefix1.prefix2.middle.suffix1.suffix2'],
    [
        [null, 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', null], 'prefix.middle.suffix'],
    [
        ['name'], 'name'],
    [
        [null], ''],
    [
        [null, null, null, null], ''],
    [
        ['a', null, null, null], 'a'],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'b'], 'b'],
    [
        [], ''],
    [
        ['prefix', null, 'suffix'], Error],
    [
        [null, null, 'a', 'b', 'c', null, null], 'a.b.c'],
    [
        ['a', null, 'b'], Error],
    [
        [null, 'middle', null], 'middle'],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, 'middle2', 'middle3', null], Error],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', 'middle2', 'middle3', null, 'middle4', 'middle5', null], Error],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, null, null, null, 'middle2', null], Error]
];

function test(fn) {
    var length = tests.length,
        index,
        expected,
        args,
        actual;

    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
        args = tests[index][0];
        expected = tests[index][1];
        if (typeof expected === 'string') {
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }

            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else if (expected === Error) {
            expected = 'middle evaluates false';
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }

            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else {
            log('Test ' + index + ': coder error');
        }
    }
}

test(getLookupKey);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.32.2/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Simple but less efficient again, in lodash (may be more efficient than ES5 and most likely better than ES6, no jsPerf available to test assumptions at present).

```js
function getLookupKey() {
    var slice =_(arguments).dropWhile(_.isEmpty).dropRightWhile(_.isEmpty);
    
    if (!slice.all(Boolean)) {
        throw new SyntaxError('middle evaluates false');
    }
    
    return slice.join('.');
}

function log(str) {
    document.getElementById('out').textContent += str + '\n';
}

var tests = [
    [
        [null, 'middle'], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'middle', null, null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, 'middle', null, null, null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        ['prefix1', 'prefix2', 'middle', 'suffix1', 'suffix2'], 'prefix1.prefix2.middle.suffix1.suffix2'
    ],
    [
        [null, 'prefix', 'middle', 'suffix', null], 'prefix.middle.suffix'
    ],
    [
        ['name'], 'name'
    ],
    [
        [null], ''
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, null], ''
    ],
    [
        ['a', null, null, null], 'a'
    ],
    [
        [null, null, null, 'b'], 'b'
    ],
    [
        [], ''
    ],
    [
        ['prefix', null, 'suffix'], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, null, 'a', 'b', 'c', null, null], 'a.b.c'
    ],
    [
        ['a', null, 'b'], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle', null], 'middle'
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, 'middle2', 'middle3', null], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', 'middle2', 'middle3', null, 'middle4', 'middle5', null], Error
    ],
    [
        [null, 'middle1', null, null, null, null, 'middle2', null], Error
    ]
];

function test(fn) {
    var length = tests.length,
        index,
        expected,
        args,
        actual;

    for (index = 0; index < length; index += 1) {
        args = tests[index][0];
        expected = tests[index][1];
        if (typeof expected === 'string') {
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }
          
            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else if (expected === Error) {
            expected = 'middle evaluates false';
            try {
                actual = fn.apply(null, args);
            } catch (e) {
                actual = e.message;
            }
          
            log('Test ' + index + ': Expected: "' + expected + '" Actual: "' + actual + '"');
        } else {
            log('Test ' + index + ': coder error');
        }
    }
}

test(getLookupKey);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

Comment: No specific Lodash requirement. Since my problem is solved already, I'll wait for some others to give votes before I give the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

[dropWhile()](https://lodash.com/docs#dropWhile) and [dropRightWhile()](https://lodash.com/docs#dropRightWhile) are your friends:

```
function getLookupKey() {
    var falsey = _.negate(_.identity);

    var result = _(arguments)
        .dropWhile(falsey)
        .dropRightWhile(falsey)
        .join('.');

    if (_.includes(result, '..')) {
        throw new Error('invalid');
    } else if (_.isUndefined(result)) {
        result = '';
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementation:

```
function getLookupKey(){
  var keyParts = trimArrayFalsey(_.toArray(arguments));
  if (! _.isArray(keyParts) || ! _.all(keyParts)) {
    throw new Error('Center null');
  }

  return keyParts.join('.');
}
```

Dependent methods:

```
var _ = require("lodash");

/**
 *  getArrayRightFalsyCount(array, [predicate=_.identity])
 *  Get a count of the contiguous falsey members on the right of the array.
 */
function getArrayRightFalsyCount(arr, predicate){
  if (! _.isArray(arr)) return 0;
  predicate = predicate || _.identity;
  return _.reduce(arr, function(result, value, index){
    return predicate(value) ? 0 : result + 1;
  }, 0);
}

/**
 *  getArrayLeftFalsyCount(array, [predicate=_.identity])
 *  Get a count of the contiguous falsey members on the left of the array.
 */
function getArrayLeftFalsyCount(arr, predicate){
  if (! _.isArray(arr)) return 0;
  return _.reduceRight(arr, function(result, value, index){
    return value ? 0 : result + 1;
  }, 0);
}

/**
 *  trimArrayFalsey(array, [predicate=_.identity])
 *  Trims the contiguous falsey members from the left and
 *  right edge of the array, but not from the middle.
 */
function trimArrayFalsey(arr, predicate){
  if (! _.isArray(arr)) return null;
  return _.slice(
    arr,
    getArrayLeftFalsyCount(arr, predicate),
    arr.length - getArrayRightFalsyCount(arr, predicate)
  );
}
```

Testing it:

```
getArrayRightFalsyCount(["a", false, "b", false, null, "", 0]);
// => 4

getArrayLeftFalsyCount([0, "", null, false, "b", false, "a"]);
// => 4

trimArrayFalsey([]);
// => []

trimArrayFalsey(["a", "b", "c"]);
// => ["a", "b", "c"]

trimArrayFalsey([null, null, false, "a", null, "b", "c", 0, ""]);
// => ["a", null, "b", "c"]

getLookupKey(null, null, "a", "b", "c", null, null);
// => "a.b.c"

getLookupKey("a", null, "b");
// => Uncaught Error: Center null
```

Comment: I did edit the answer and I hope that makes it clearer, however I've seen plenty of answers that are just code with no explination at all and I don't see what's wrong with that as long as it addresses the question.

Comment: I personally downvote such posts as they are generally not helpful. We try to be a knowledge repository, not a copy-and-paste source alone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This is a unique answer that I wrote myself. It's an answer to the question and even before the edit has code that addresses the answer. I appreciate your opinion, I just wish I understood it better.

Comment: I will also note that I've personally upvoted all the other answers, because I feel they are better answers than mine. I'm glad I asked this question and have no regrets posting an answer to my own question as I've gotten new insight into the problem.

Comment: Note that it wasn't me that voted on this post; I now see that there is are two votes (and not 0). I was talking in general. I commented on your post because it was flagged as *Not an answer*, which is why I asked you to clarify the answer. Someone *else* thought it wasn't very helpful and voted accordingly.